# Make PhpStorm respect v-if for variable resolution in a project with Vue 3, Pinia, and TypeScript

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, phpstorm, webstorm, pinia

I'm using JetBrains PhpStorm for a Vue 3 project that utilizes TypeScript and a Pinia store. The Pinia store defines a variable `currentSnackbar=ref<ISnackbar>()`. The value may be undefined or an object that conforms to the `ISnackbar` interface. In the Vue template, I verify that the value is not undefined using `v-if`. Inside that `v-if`, I should then be able to safely access the properties defined in the `ISnackbar` interface.

Inside the v-if statement, PhpStorm is correctly identifying the type of the `currentSnackbar` as `ISnackbar|undefined`.

[image: PhpStorm screenshot]

However, PhpStorm seems to ignore the `v-if` statement when referencing `currentSnackbar` inside of the element with the `v-if`. PhpStorm shows that `currentSnackbar` may be undefined:

[image: PhpStorm screenshot]

Referencing a property defined in the `ISnackbar` interface, then gives an "unresolved variable reference":

[image: PhpStorm screenshot]

ISnackbar.ts:

```typescript
export default interface ISnackbar {
  id: string
  message: string
  color: string
  timeout: number
}
```

ui.store.ts:

```typescript
export const useUiStore = defineStore('ui', () => {
  const currentSnackbar: Ref<ISnackbar|undefined> = ref<ISnackbar>()
})
```

App.vue:

```vue
<script lang="ts" setup>
import {useUiStore} from "@/store/ui.store";
const uiStore = useUiStore()
</script>
<template>
  <div v-if="uiStore.currentSnackbar">
    {{ uiStore.currentSnackbar.message }}
  </div>
</template>
```

Given this code, I expect `{{ uiStore.currentSnackbar.message }}` to be fully resolved by the IDE.

I can resolve the IDE error by changing `{{ uiStore.currentSnackbar.message }}` to `{{ uiStore.currentSnackbar?.message }}` but the optional chaining should be unnecessary if the IDE respected the v-if.

Do I have a logical error that I'm not seeing? If not, what do I need to do to make PhpStorm respect the `v-if`?

Comment: Please submit a new issue in https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB and provide a sample project where it can be reproduced.

Comment: Until jetbrains releases a fix for this, use optional chaining inside the `v-if`.